# How do I updateSelectInput() on the same dataset multiple times

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Here I'm using 'mtcars' and will like to update my selectInputs based on the unique values in some column. First, we choose the type of engine and subset the data. Then we choose the cylinder but based on the remaining cylinder options in the subsetted data, and so forth. Last, we print the names of the cars. Code, which is not working, is as below:

```
library(shiny)

df <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("engine", "Select engine:", choices = unique(df$vs)),
    selectInput("cylinder", "Select cylinder:", choices = ""),
    selectInput("gear", "Select gear:", choices = ""),
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("results")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$engine, {
    tmp <- df
    tmp1 <- tmp[tmp$vs == as.numeric(input$engine),]
    updateSelectInput(session, "cylinder", choices = unique(tmp1$cyl))
    data()$tmp1 <- tmp1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$cylinder,{
    tmp1 <- data()$tmp1
    tmp2 <- tmp1[tmp1$cyl == as.numeric(input$cylinder),]
    updateSelectInput(session, "gear", choices = unique(tmp2$gear))
    data()$tmp2 <- tmp2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gear,{
    tmp2 <- data()$tmp2
    tmp3 <- tmp2[tmp2$gear == as.numeric(input$gear),]
    data()$tmp3 <- tmp3
  })
  
  output$results <- renderText({
    print(row.names(data()$tmp3))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you try to access your `reactiveValues` `data` using `data()`. Instead, to set or get a value use e.g. `data$tmp1` without parentheses. See `?reactiveValues`.

```r
library(shiny)

df <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("engine", "Select engine:", choices = unique(df$vs)),
    selectInput("cylinder", "Select cylinder:", choices = ""),
    selectInput("gear", "Select gear:", choices = ""),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("results")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$engine, {
    tmp <- df
    tmp1 <- tmp[tmp$vs == input$engine, ]
    updateSelectInput(session, "cylinder", choices = unique(tmp1$cyl))
    data$tmp1 <- tmp1
  })

  observeEvent(input$cylinder, {
    tmp1 <- data$tmp1
    tmp2 <- tmp1[tmp1$cyl == input$cylinder, ]
    updateSelectInput(session, "gear", choices = unique(tmp2$gear))
    data$tmp2 <- tmp2
  })

  observeEvent(input$gear, {
    tmp2 <- data$tmp2
    tmp3 <- tmp2[tmp2$gear == input$gear, ]
    data$tmp3 <- tmp3
  })

  output$results <- renderText({
    print(row.names(data$tmp3))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5721
#> character(0)
#> [1] "Mazda RX4"     "Mazda RX4 Wag"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was the same access method as reactive(). Do you know a more elegant way of doing this?